# Get the pointer coordinates with GTK3 C++

Tags: c++, gtk

I am looking for a function in GTK+ that can tell me the coordinates of the cursor (x,y) also that works with Linux operating systems.

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check of the documentation turned up [`gdk_window_get_device_position()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-get-device-position), which should work even outside mouse events. (I have not tried it myself.) The caveat here is that this is for **GDK** windows, not what most people think of as windows (i.e. **GTK+** windows). One path from a GTK+ widget to a GDK window is [`gtk_widget_get_window()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window).

As for working on Linux, GTK+ is designed to be cross-platform, so everything should work on Linux unless specifically documented otherwise.

Comment: does it have to have a window to get the position?